# zeroclipboard is not working. ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath is not a function

Tags: javascript, clipboard, zeroclipboard

Good day, friends. I can't make zeroclipboard working with my page. In HTML page I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script> //Script was loaded successfully.

 ...

 <button id="copy_clipboard">Test me</button>
 <script>
  ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('http://olymp/ZeroClipboard.swf'); //Path correct. It's local php server 
  var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
  clip.setText('test');
  clip.glue('copy_clipboard');
 </script>
```

This return me an error:
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath is not a function

After deleting

```
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('http://olymp/ZeroClipboard.swf');
```

I got an error:

ZeroClipboard.Client is not a constructor

Comment: Swf has to reside on same domain as that code. Does it?

Comment: sure. swf is on the same domain

Comment: I've tried another variant of using zeroclipboard:


 var clip = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy_clipboard"), {
  moviePath: "http://olymp/ZeroClipboard.swf",
  text: "test"
 } );
 clip.setText('test');

It doesn't return any errors. but my text 'test' not copied to the clipboard :(

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would help a little bit:

Try using:

```
ZeroClipboard.setDefaults({moviePath: 'http://olymp/ZeroClipboard.swf'});
```

And also:

```
var clip = new ZeroClipboard();
```

For your another question, try using :

```
clip.on('dataRequested', function(client, args){
     clip.setText("YOUR TEXT HERE");
});
```

instead of using clip.setText alone :)

Answer (score 1):

sometimes you need to init the zeroclipboard client on document ready

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var client = new ZeroClipboard($('#buttonId'), {
            moviePath : 'util/ZeroClipboard.swf'
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="button" id="buttonId" data-clipboard-target="inputId" />
<input type="text" id="inputId" />
```

will copy in cplipboard the contents of the input text, for me it worked also for localhost